# How to authorise on GAE application from desktop application by using OAUTH2.0

Tags: google-app-engine

I try to authorise on my GAE application from desktop client.
How I do it.

1. create client secret and id in Developer console.
2. Get Authorisation code from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

> { "scope" : "profile email",...}

3. Get Refresh token and Access token from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

And  there is magic for me:

If I send access token directly in request header:

> Authorization: Bearer "access token"

to  my application end-point.
I received `STATUS 401`.

I found that to authorise need to use `end-pointhttp://<my_project_id>.appspot.com/_ah/login?auth=<access_token>`

but this call always returns: `STATUS 500`, as I understand means that token is expired or invalid.

What is invalid in my workflow?
Where I can obtain the valid access token?

Comment: Your scopes dont look right. Try on the oauth2 playground so you understand the flow

Comment: I do not have problem with obtain access token. What scopes do need use?
The scopes as described here https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes

Comment: Aha you are using the g+ library. Then scopes are ok.